# every row from the database being one JList item?

Tags: java, sql

I currently have a database that is working well. It displays the text from each column of the database into 5 labels on the app user interface. Some of the time, depending on what the user enters, I want it to display a list of rows from the database, I was thinking of using the JList.

the current code to display to the labels is:

```
String sqlQuery = "select Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5 from APP.DATA123 " + 
"where (Column1 = ?) AND (Column2 = ?) AND (Column3 = ?) OR (Column1 = ?) AND (Column2 = ?)";

String abc = jTextField2.getText();
String cba = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
String cab = (String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
String data = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample";
    try (
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
          data, "app", "app");
          PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery))   { 

      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
      st.setString(1, abc);
      st.setString(2, cba);
      st.setString(3, cab);       
      st.setString(4, cba);
      st.setString(5, cab);
      ResultSet rec = st.executeQuery();
        while (rec.next())  {
          jLabel1.setText(rec.getString("Column1"));
          jLabel2.setText(rec.getString("Column2"));
          jLabel3.setText(rec.getString("Column3"));
          jLabel4.setText(rec.getString("Column4"));
          jLabel5.setText(rec.getString("Column5"));

      }
      st.close();
```

Is there an easier way to make it so that if there is more than one row of the database to be displayed to the user, I can make a JList so that all of the columns of one row (and possibly an image but I'll think about that later), are displayed as one item on the JList. So Columns1-5 are one JlistItem, and then columns 1-5 for the next database row are the next JList item etc?

Or another similar way that anyone knows of?

There is not that much text per column only about 5-15 characters.

Comment: Use a JTable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your JList to a ListModel implementation and fill that ListModel. In your case - each item in your ListModel is a concatenated string of all items from each row in ResultSet. Something like following :

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList list = new JList(model);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);//add the "pane" to your form next line

String abc = jTextField2.getText();
String cba = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
String cab = (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
String data = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample";
    try(
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        data, "app", "app");
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery))

{

    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    st.setString(1, "abc");
    st.setString(2, "cba");
    st.setString(3, "cab");
    st.setString(4, "cba");
    st.setString(5, "cab");
    ResultSet rec = st.executeQuery();

    // may want to make it constant (final static)
    final String SPACE = " ";
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while (rec.next()) {
        sBuilder.setLength(0);
        sBuilder
             .append(rec.getString("Column1")).append(SPACE)
             .append(rec.getString("Column2")).append(SPACE)
             .append(rec.getString("Column3")).append(SPACE)
             .append(rec.getString("Column4")).append(SPACE)
             .append(rec.getString("Column5")).append(SPACE);

        model.addElement(sBuilder.toString());

    }
    st.close();
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJListwithaDefaultListModel.htm) article, might be very helpful in your case. And, BTW, googling or reading docs is much faster than writing a question on SO and waiting for answer =). Cheers.

Comment: When I use the line of code that states 
" JList list = new JList(model);"
It gives a rejection stating either the variable is not in use(because my jlist is called "jList1") OR if I replace list with jList1 it states "local variable hides a field". So I replaced it with "jList1.setModel(model);" it now gets no rejections but dose not work. 

Also, when I created the jList, it auto populated with a few items within it called "item1, item2 etc etc". I havn't done anything to remove these and wasn't sure if that is whats causing the problem.....